# Python - import module which imports module

Tags: python, class, module

I have three scripts in the same location:

```
   /__init__.py
    interface.py
    radio.py
    playlist.py
```

`playlist.py` has child classes stored, like:

```
class playlist1(radio):
    '''child class'''
```

and `radio.py` has the parent class:

```
class radio(object):
    '''parent class'''
```

I'm trying to run `interface.py`, which has:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from playlist import *
```

in `playlist.py` I have this import, on its turn:

```
from radio import radio
```

but when I run `interface.py`, I get the following error:

`ImportError: cannot import name radio`

I use `python 2.x`. what's wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using just the setup you've shown here.  If I create the three files you showed, with the contents you showed (plus empty `__init__.py`), I can run `interface.py` without errors.  I suspect there is something else going on in one of the files, or perhaps you have another file called `radio.py` somewhere else that is being imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of the situation has omitted a crucial part: the package where these modules live. For example, if they live in the `foo` package, the situation would look like this:

```
foo/
    __init__.py
    interface.py
    radio.py
    playlist.py
```

In that context, there are two common ways for the `playlist` module to import names from the `radio` module:

```
# 1. Fully qualified.
from foo.radio import radio

# 2. Relative import.
from .radio import radio
```

The second approach is strongly recommended because it leaves no room for ambiguity.

You also haven't told us how you are running `interface.py`. Those details can affect the importing situation as well.

If you are organizing code in packages, you need to follow a conventional
project structure. In this layout, you would tend to work in the project
root. Also you need a proper `setup.py` file. Here's what it might look like:

```
# ----
# Directory layout.
some_project/
    foo/
        __init__.py
        interface.py
        playlist.py
        radio.py
    setup.py

    # You work at this level.

# ----
# interface.py 

from playlist import radio

def main():
    print radio

# ----
# playlist.py

from .radio import radio

# ----
# radio.py

radio = 123

# ----
# setup.py

from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name     = 'foo',
    version  = '1.0',
    zip_safe = False,
    packages = ['foo'],
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            'foobar = foo.interface:main',
        ],
    },
)

# ----
# Install stuff for dev work (ie in "editable" mode).
pip install -e .

# ----
# Run the command line entry point.
foobar
```

Comment: isn't `dot`notation for `python 3.x`? mine is `2.x`. If I do what you say, I get `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`. all files are at root.

Comment: If you are organizing code in packages, you need to follow a standard project structure. Putting everything in the root directory and running code from the root won't work well for various reasons -- starting with the fact that Python won't interpret the root directory as a package. There are various resources on this topic, but here's one: https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/

Comment: @data_garden I added some more details on project structure

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to make an empty file called

```
__init__.py
```

in the same directory as the files. That will let Python2 knows that it's okay to import from this directory.
Then use your code.

Comment: it's already there, I forgot to mention that and have done it now on my edit. sorry.

Comment: By any chance do you have circular imports?